# Can't set up data in space in Power BI

Tags: azure, powerbi

I'm trying to set up data in space for mobile.

In my Azure Portal, I have created a Spatial Anchors resource group.

Given myself Owner role permissions for the resource group:

[image]

In Power BI tenant, I'm the administrator and I log in with the same account.

But, I can't connect to Azure from Power BI Service:

[image]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to create a Management Group in Azure and delete it again.

I wasted an awful amount of time to fix this, and have no idea why it now works, but wasn't working before...

Just in case anyone bumps into this.